Why is there an error with 'Collision.gameObject.tag'?
Visual Studio and Unity are giving me an error saying [tag:CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, methhod, or property 'Collision.gameObject'] It's in line 21 [tag:if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Door")].
The script is meant to have it so that when an object collides with a Door (Has seperate "Door" Tag), it'll enable the Door's Animator, and run an animation (Open), then stop it so it doesn't repeat. Any suggestions or improvements are also welcome. I've seen other people use the same thing, but I'm just given the error. What's wrong, and how could I fix it?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator doorAnim;
    public GameObject Door;
    private BoxCollider boxCollider;

    public void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        doorAnim = Door.GetComponent<Animator>();
        doorAnim.enabled = false;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Door")
         {
            doorAnim.enabled = true;
            doorAnim.Play("Open");
            doorAnim.StopPlayback();
         }
    }

}

As said previously, I tried the before script, and ended up with the error [tag:CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, methhod, or property 'Collision.gameObject']. I expected it just to have it so when a box collides with a door, it enables it's animator, runs an animation, then stops; But the part of detecting the door collision had and error.
This is the errored Line: [tag:if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "Door")]
And this is the errored section: collision.gameobject

Seems like a typo - you're grabbing the 'gameobject' property from the Collision type, not the collision object you're passing to the function. You need to make "collision" lowercase in your if statement

Because Collision.gameObject.tag refers to the class not the variable. So you meant collision. Hence often you see it as "other" to make it easier to spot the issue

imho other only makes sense for Collider .. for a Collision it should stay collision

true, but it does help newer people differntiate between the class and variable name.. as it stands its not an uncommon mistake

Hm yeah .. though tbh I would rather claim this is something you should get used to and learn to understand compiler errors .. and basic c# syntax like that casing matters and the difference between a class and variable name ^^ The same you could argue for any other place GameObject gameobject, Transform transform or from OP's code BoxCollider boxCollider

Oh i dont disagree.  Programming is about detail. And missing the distinction is a key issue.

Thank you for the help! I could've sworn I tried lowercase collision , I guess not, but thank you anyways!
